# Error when mapping classes with attribute that has foreign key

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the **Hardware** entity, **HardwareDtoRequest** and **HardwareDtoResponse** classes, where I'm using the modelMapper to map them. In the Hardware table, there is a foreign key to the Provider table.
The problem is that I am not able to map this attribute to HardwareDtoRequest, when I call the POST method in Postman passing only the provider_id in the request body it saves only one record with that particular ID, when trying to save again another record with the same ID it updates the old one.
How do I map this foreign key attribute to the DtoRequest and save?

**Hardware.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Hardware {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
private Provider provider;

}
```

**Provider.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Provider {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
private String name;

}
```

**HardwareDtoRequest.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HardwareDtoRequest {

@NotNull(message = "required field")
private String name;

@NotNull(message = "required field")
private Long providerId;

}
```

**HardwareDtoResponse.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HardwareDtoResponse {

private Long id;
private String name;
private ProviderDtoResponse provider;

}
```

**HardwareMapper.java**

```
public HardwareDtoResponse toHardwareDtoResponse(Hardware hardware) {
        
    return mapper.map(hardware, HardwareDtoResponse.class);
}
    
public Hardware toHardware(HardwareDtoRequest hardwareDtoRequest) {
        
    return mapper.map(hardwareDtoRequest, Hardware.class);
}
```

**HardwareService.java**

```
@Transactional
public HardwareDtoResponse save(HardwareDtoRequest hardwareDtoRequest) {
        
    Hardware hardware = mapper.toHardware(hardwareDtoRequest);
        
    Hardware saveHardware = hardwareRepository.save(hardware);

    return mapper.toHardwareDtoResponse(saveHardware);
}
```

**HardwareController.java**

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<HardwareDtoResponse> save(@Valid @RequestBody HardwareDtoRequest hardwareDtoRequest) {
        
    log.info("saving hardware: {}", hardwareDtoRequest);    

    HardwareDtoResponse hardware = hardwareService.save(hardwareDtoRequest);
        
    return new ResponseEntity<>(hardware, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set provider manually. Like this:

```java
public Hardware toHardware(HardwareDtoRequest hardwareDtoRequest) {
    Hardware hardware = mapper.map(hardwareDtoRequest, Hardware.class);
    Provider provider = providerRepository.findById(hardwareDtoRequest.providerId);
    hardware.setProvider(provider);
    return hardware;
}
```

Comment: i tried this way and still without success, i can't save more than one record with the same provider_id.

Comment: Of course, because `provider_id` is the ID from the table `Provider`, it will replace the same id. What is your expected result? Please explain more and give the example.

Comment: I'm sending in the body of the request:
`{
    "name": "Notebook Microsoft 554",
    "propertyNumber": "475125A",
    "description": "Notebook Microsoft, 16GB RAM, 2T",
    "providerId": 1,
    "receivedDate": "15-12-2022",
    "warrantyTime": "3 years"
}`

Comment: But when changing from Provider provider to Long providerId in my DtoResponse, I can only save one record with that provider_id. If I leave it as Provider provider in DtoResponse, it usually saves several records with the same provider_id, but I have to send all the Provider data and not just the id in the request.

Comment: I think modelMapper is not able to map Provider to Long providerId in my DtoRequest.

Comment: I know that provider_id is the ID from the table Provider, but when i try to save one hardware with the same provider_id, it doesn't save another record in Hardware table.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it, for those who have the same problem of mapping dtos with modelMapper, I use the following snippet in ModelMapperConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ModelMapperConfig {

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper mapper() {
        
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        
        return modelMapper;
    }
}
```